# Tkinter button with transparant background

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make the background of a button transparant.
I'm using a transparant image for the button background.
However, the button keeps on showing the button itself.
Any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
def StartMakePic(dummy):
    True

win = Tk()
win.geometry("600x400+0+0")
bgImage = Image.open("bg.png")
bgRendered = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgImage)
bg = Button(win)
bg.config(image = bgRendered, command = lambda:StartMakePic(1))
bg.place(x=0,y=0)
camera_image = Image.open("camera_pic.png")
camera_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(camera_image)
button2 = Button(win, width=120,height=120, image=camera_photo, compound=CENTER, bd=0,highlightthickness=0,command = lambda:StartMakePic(1))
button2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

while True:
    win.update()
```

Tk result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRXXl.jpg)

bg image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaMaD.png)
Button2 image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXh8l.png)

Tried many things like win.wm_attributes

Comment: Tk widgets are opaque rectangles.  Anything that would require that a widget be something other than an opaque rectangle has no possibility of working.

Comment: There is no cross-platform way to make just the background transparent in tkinter.